# Does vscode deactivate the virtual environment when vscode is closed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-venv

Seeking assistance with understanding how VSCode works.

I am able to switch the interpreter via the Select Interpreter command. Upon doing this, the python interpreter is shown in the bottom right corner:

[virtual environment which is being activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPLKp.png)

Does VSCode deactivate the virtual environment when I close VSCode, if at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Activating" an environment, when doing it on the command line, mostly just sets a bunch of environment variables to point at a specific folder, so that folder is where Python tries to locate its executable and packages. That's pretty much it. There's nothing persistently running or anything. "Deactivating" just restores those environment variables to their defaults, so you're using the system Python again.

You don't need to activate an environment at all to use it. If you set the correct environment variables *while calling the right Python executable*, you run your code in the environment without having "activated" it. That's what VSC is doing when you use it to run code. "Activating" is only used on the command line so save you from having to type in long commands with environment variables each time you want to invoke Python.

Comment: Sorry, from my understanding, there are activate and deactivate scripts that exist in the venv folder that are called when one types in the relevant commands. From the post does that mean VSC might not even call the scripts activate / deactivate as it calls the python executable with the correct environment variables? And that would mean that after the executable is called every thing is restored without the need for the deactivate script that would otherwise have to be called manually?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. — If you `activate` the environment on the command line and then simply close it without executing `deactivate`, nothing bad is going to happen either.

Comment: Does the deactivate script just give one more freedom to set the environment variables back, without having to close the application in that case?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you're asking, but yes: `deactivate` just restores the relevant environment variables to their default. No more, no less.

Comment: @CCsk probably it is important to understand that environment variable are *local to a process*. if you close the application, then the process ceases to exist.